# Implementing heartbeat in terms of best practice

Tags: .net, asp.net, node.js, jquery

I have a web application that is running under .NET framework and that is using JS/JQuery on the client side. I am the owner and the only developer of this web application, and it is not totally under production. This just to say that I can change the whole architecture of this application with no problem.

I want to implement heartbeat on the client side so that I can know who is connected and who is not and also to inform the user if there are any live updates etc.... My biggest fear is that I am not sure if I do implement it myself that it would slow down the system on the future. So I have a lot of questions in mind :

- Is 5 secondes good as an interval between each heartbeat
- Can a 5 secondes heartbeat slow down the system ?
- How can I implement it in terms of best practice, can I simply do a setInterval and send an ajax request to the server every 5 secondes ?
- I heard that nodejs have also this option, should I migrate some part to nodejs (I am not a nodejs expert)

PS: my app will have only 100-300 clients on the future

Comment: What problem does "who'd connected and who isn't " actually solve? Purely for reporting?

Comment: Yes only for reporting. But on the hand I need to send sometimes some urgent notifications to the client and that's the main reason why I need to do heartbeats.

Comment: The heartbeat interval is entirely dependent on software requirements.  If the software needs to know every five seconds that a client is alive, then that's the heartbeat interval you'll have to set.  I doubt very much that it's five seconds, though.  More like once a minute, at the very most.

Comment: Be very careful when asking these questions not to say how to implement them. Tell us only your needs. You might make more work then necessary. I suspect researching a concept called “long polling” would help you rethink your approach. “connected” is rarely what humans really care about.

Comment: Did you consider web sockets?

Comment: @candied_orange "setInterval and send an ajax request to the server every 5 secondes"

Answer (score 2):

Client heartbeat is bad practice.

There's no scenario explanation in your question, but you have to consider: what happens when the heartbeat misses? What's the server supposed to do?

Basically, in a client-server architecture you don't put the server waiting for a response from the client (and even less so a timed response).

You might want to do a timed polling instead, for instance.

Comment: I've already created a variable called "Attempts" already initialized to zero, if the heartbeat misses the variable is incremented otherwise it goes to zero. and if reach 5 (5 misses in a row) a disconnect message is displayed

Comment: I would describe a heartbeat _as_ timed polling, i.e. polling the web server on a regular interval. How is timed polling different from a heartbeat? It may improve the answer to elaborate on the details.

Answer (score 1):

As with many software projects, the starting point is to disambiguate the requirements.

> So that I can know who is connected and who is not

Let's rewrite this in a specific way. It could mean

- Which users are sitting at the desk looking at the page - this cannot be achieved
- Which users have a window or tab open to the page? - this cannot be achieved
- Which users have a active authentication session that has not timed out - this can be achieved without heartbeat
- Which users have requested a page in the last XXX seconds - this can be achieved without heartbeat

My conclusion here is that a heartbeat is not the right fit for the problem. Unless you can specify some other requirement that it meets.

Then there is this:

> and also to inform the user if there are any live updates

This might mean

- Ensure that live update notifications are rendered at the top of the page when the user accesses the site - this can be achieved without heartbeat
- Ensure that live update notifications pop up on the screen the moment they are available - this is probably not reliably achievable, and would be annoying AF honestly
- Update a badge or indicator of some kind immediately without requiring a page refresh (sort of like StackOverflow's reputation badge) - this would probably be best achieved through polling, which is sort of a heartbeat.

For this very last possibility in the list, yes, it would make sense to use setInterval and send an AJAX request every few seconds. There is not much more to it than that.